# Calculate average of temperatures and math.round?

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I'm trying to solve an assignment in my javascript class. So the assignment is to calculate the average of some different temperatures in different cities. We should use arrays and I think I made most of the assignment but now I want to use math.round to round off the numbers. But I don't know where I should place the math.round, I guess it's a really simple question but I don't get it to work. I also want to get rid of the "NaN" that you can see in the upper right. Thankful for help!

My code look like this:

```js
var temp = [
  ["City", "00-08", "08-16", "16-24", "Average"],
  ["New York", 12, 16, 9],
  ["London", 13, 15, 10],
  ["Stockholm", 13, 15, 13],
  ["Oslo", 14, 16, 15],
  ["Hong Kong", 13, 14, 12]
];

function printit() {
  var MyinnerHTML = "<table border='1'>";

  for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) //Loop vertical 
  {
    MyinnerHTML += "<tr>";
    for (j = 0; j < temp[i].length; j++) //Loop horisontal 
    {
      MyinnerHTML += "<td>" + temp[i][j] + "</td>";
    } {
      total = temp[i][1] + temp[i][2] + temp[i][3];

      temp[i].shift(); //So it doesn't calculate the average with the city name

      average = total / temp[i].length;

    }

    {
      MyinnerHTML += "<td>" + average + "</td>";
    }
    MyinnerHTML += "<tr/>";
  }
  MyinnerHTML += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = MyinnerHTML;
}
```

```html
<h1> Temperature in different cities (Assignment1) </h1>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Want it to look like this when it's finished.

[image]

Comment: Don't you want the city names in the output? Also, I don't see any table output in the snippet.

Comment: I guess you should round the average, so: `average = Math.round( total / temp[i].length );`

Comment: toFixed was designed to solve this sort of problem, but it will floor not round. I believe that is  standard though

Answer (score 0):

You can get that rounded number by first multiplying the average with 10, applying `Math.round` on it, and then divide it again by 10. Here is how I would suggest creating the HTML code:

```js
const temp = [
  ["City", "00-08", "08-16", "16-24", "Average"],
  ["New York", 12, 16, 9],
  ["London", 13, 15, 10],
  ["Stockholm", 13, 15, 13],
  ["Oslo", 14, 16, 15],
  ["Hong Kong", 13, 14, 12]
];

const html = temp.map( (row, i) => {
    if (i) {
        const avg = row.slice(1).reduce( (a,b) => a+b ) / (row.length-1);
        row.push(Math.round(avg*10)/10);
    }
    return '<td>' + row.join('</td><td>') + '</td>';
}).join('</tr><tr>');

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = 
    "<table border='1'><tr>" + html + "</tr></table>";
```

```html
<h3> Temperature in different cities (Assignment1) </h3>
<div id="container"></div>
```